# exporting data from Neo4j to csv using java

Tags: neo4j

what is the best methodology to export data from Neo4j to CSV, I had imported data from csv to neo4j using CSV importer in the link https://github.com/sroycode/neo4j-import.

I had performed some operations on the data, i want to get back the query results into the csv, can anyone suggest me the solution.

iam using neo4j 1.9.3 and java 1.6

Comment: You want separate node and relationship csv files I suppose?

Comment: i dont know the best way..getting nodes and relationship in separate files is best..?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Ignore my question, I misread.

Comment: @Luanne is there any way with java..?

Comment: @Luanne or any other way..?

Comment: See Stefan's answer- you can use opencsv in java

Answer (score 3):

A short snippet in `Groovy` doing this:

```
@Grab(group="org.neo4j", module="neo4j-cypher", version="1.9")
@Grab(group='net.sf.opencsv', module='opencsv', version='2.3') 
import org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter

assert args, "specify location of graph.db and cypher statement"

def db = new org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase(args[0])
def ee = new ExecutionEngine(db)
def result = ee.execute(args[1])
def columns = result.columns()

System.out.withWriter { writer ->
    CSVWriter csv = new CSVWriter(writer)
    csv.writeNext(columns as String[])

    for (def row in result) {
        def values = columns.collect {row[it]}
        csv.writeNext(values as String[])
    }
}
db.shutdown()
```

Of course `opencsv` can be used in a pure Java environment as well.

Comment: thanks for reply Stefan..but is there any way with java..because i already used java.

Comment: you can easily transpose the snippet above to plain old java - should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

As you already have the ids, you can get the ids and their fwd relationships in chunks (of 5) using cypher, the csv separator is '|'

To test use neo4j-shell 
Syntax: neo4j-shell < infile > outfile

infile for node looks like

```
START n=node(1,2,3,4,5) return ID(n),n.name?,n.property?;
START n=node(6,7,8,9,10) return ID(n),n.name?,n.property?;
....
```

infile for reln looks like

```
START n=node(1,2,3,4,5) MATCH n-[r]->m RETURN ID(n),ID(m),TYPE(r),r.someprop?;
START n=node(6,7,8,9,10) MATCH n-[r]->m RETURN ID(n),ID(m),TYPE(r),r.someprop?;
....
```

To do the same thing in the Java API , just run the same in a for loop.