# COnverting neo4j DB to csv

Tags: neo4j, export-to-csv

[This may seem similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361565/exporting-data-from-neo4j-to-csv-using-java)

But the previous answer shows how to convert a cypher result to csv.

How to export(dump/convert) the whole neo4j database to .csv format?

I am using neo4j-2.0 embedded with my java application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a graph database is by design schemaless it's almost impossible to generically export it to csv format. Neo4j enterprise edition comes with a online backup features that is a consistent dump in machine readable format - so not csv.